# How to write void pointer typedefs in vapi files?

Tags: binding, odbc, vala, vapi

I'm trying to write a VAPI file to use unixODBC, one of the functions is called `SQLAllocHandle`:

```
// From <sqltypes.h>
#define SQL_API
typedef signed short int SQLSMALLINT;
typedef SQLSMALLINT      SQLRETURN;
typedef void *           SQLHANDLE;

// From <sql.h>
#define SQL_SUCCESS                0
#define SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO      1
#define SQL_ERROR                 (-1)
#define SQL_INVALID_HANDLE        (-2)

#define SQL_HANDLE_ENV             1
#define SQL_HANDLE_DBC             2
#define SQL_HANDLE_STMT            3
#define SQL_HANDLE_DESC            4

#define SQL_NULL_HANDLE            0

SQLRETURN SQL_API SQLAllocHandle(SQLSMALLINT HandleType, SQLHANDLE InputHandle, SQLHANDLE *OutputHandle);
```

It's my first try to write a vapi file, but the documentation is scarce at the moment ([Vala vapi files documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496656/vala-vapi-files-documentation)).

The calling code should look similiar to this:

```
using UnixOdbc;

int main(string[] args) {
  Handle h;
  if (AllocHandle (HandleType.ENV, NullHandle, out h) == Return.SUCCESS)
  ...
}
```

In particular I'd like to know how to convert the `SQLHANDLE` type which is really just a `void *` (opaque void pointer).

In other words, what would the `UnixOdbc.Handle` type look like in the vapi file?

My current approach is to pretend that it is a long:

```
[CCode (cheader_filename = "sql.h, sqltypes.h")]
namespace UnixOdbc {
    [CCode (cname = "SQLRETURN", cprefix = "SQL_")]
    public enum Return {
        SUCCESS,
        SUCCESS_WITH_INFO,
        ERROR,
        INVALID_HANDLE
    }
    [CCode (cname = "SQLSMALLINT", cprefix = "SQL_HANDLE_")]
    public enum HandleType {
        ENV,
        DBC,
        STMT,
        DESC
    }
    [CCode (cname = "SQLHANDLE")]
    public struct Handle: long {}

    [CCode (cname = "SQL_NULL_HANDLE")]
    public const Handle NULL_HANDLE;

    [CCode (cname = "SQLAllocHandle")]
    public static Return AllocHandle (HandleType handle_type, Handle input_handle, out Handle output_handle);
}
```

Comment: For anyone interrested in the code, I've made a github repository for it: https://github.com/antiochus/unixodbc-vala

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trying reading the [guide for legacy VAPI files](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Co-D09vA_N7YBjfyCnLojYHmzsBHg9cG5qnbzsNJ5lQ/edit). I would make:

```
[CCode(cname = "void")]
[Compact]
public class Handle {
   [CCode(cname = "SQLAllocHandle")]
   public static Return alocate_handle(HandleType type, Handle? input_handle, out Handle?  output_handle);
...
}
```

Simply disregard the binding of `SQL_NULL_HANDLE`; it doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Does this work in strict non-null mode? How is the destruction handled? In unixODBC the handle must be deallocated with `SQLFreeHandle`. I got some complaints about `unix_odbc_Handle_free` from the compiler.

Comment: You need to add `free_function="SQLFreeHandle"` in the `CCode` attribute of the class. Yes. The non-nullness of a variable is purely a Vala construct. If you have put in the appropriate `?` modifiers, it will behave as expected.

Comment: That would work, but `SQLFreeHandle` expects an additional handle type parameter. I could work around that, but I think I'll keep the `long` approach since it's much easier to work with.

Comment: You can create a static function that takes an owned handle to destroy it. It really shouldn't be a long. You can create a struct with the `[SimpleType]` modifier.

Comment: I'll try the struct version. Your guide is a very great asset, btw.

Comment: Actually if I think about it, it might be best to use an individual `[Compact] class` for each individual handle type (there are four in unixODBC). I'd have to write my own for `free_function_foo` functions, but that would have the benifit that nobody confuses the handle types.